# A sample neocomplcache setting in .vimrc is work for MacVim , but not work for Linux console vim

Tags: java, linux, macos, vim, macvim

I installed neocomplcache for vim in both my computer, macbook air and Linux ubuntu 11.10
I use macVim on macbook air, but I use console vim on ubuntu.

First,I copied the sample code to the .vimrc of macVIm. 
And it works for my macbook and no errors occurs.

After that,I copied the code to the .vimrc of console vim.
When I try to run vim on terminal every time.
It tolds me that the following sentence is wrong expression.

```
let g:neocomplcache_dictionary_filetype_lists = {\ 'default' : '',
        \ 'vimshell' : $HOME.'/.vimshell_hist',
            \ 'scheme' : $HOME.'/.gosh_completions'
              \ }
```

Although I cannot see any negative effects on the function of this plugin,(I use java completion)
what wrong it is going on??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it is missing a line break before the `\` in `s = {\ '`. This can be caused by different newline delimiters (CR vs. LF).

Comment: It's a question long time ago, I really appreciate you that you have found this post and replied it. I tried your suggestion and joined those lines. But the gVim still said that they are invalid expression.
In my point of view, the reason behind that is I am missing the file `/.vimshell_hist` and `/.gosh_completions`

Comment: When you joined the lines, have you removed the leading backslash characters? An _invalid expression_ cannot be caused by missing files, Vim doesn't even recognize then and there that files are involved.

Comment: wow you comment is just a minute after my comment.
thanks for your remind, I didn't remove those leading \ characters.
And I have remove them right now and no any errors:) . I would like to ask what is the actual meaning of  \ ??

Comment: Glad that one got finally fixed! The backslash is Vim syntax for breaking an expression over multiple lines. See `:help line-continuation`.